# Changing Root Permission

Tags: ubuntu, root, plesk

It appears that someone changed the permissions on my root folder and now, not only can I access any of my websites but I can't even change the root permissions back to where they need to be or access Plesk. This is what I am doing and getting in return:

```
chmod 777 ./
chmod: changing permissions of './': Read-only file system
```

I checked and the root has a permission of 077 set.
The website is giving me this:

```
Cannot load Dependencies for phpFox. Make sure to run composer first. Error message: Path "/var/www/vhosts/myfreeviews.com/httpdocs/PF.Base/file/cache/prod/cs/4c52_/Files" is not writable, please set a chmod 0777 or any writable permission and make sure to make use of an absolute path !
```

I'm not the greatest in Linux but I know that I did not make the change that caused this and could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
chmod 777 ./ chmod: changing permissions of './': Read-only file system
```

Says that the root file system is mounted read-only. This is not a problem with the permissions, but for some reason the FS was (re)mounted read-only, possibly because of filesystem errors on boot or some kernel exception.

This said, you should almost *never* use permissions `777` as they allow everyone, including the user `nobody` that is made for processes that should have minimal permissions, to read *and* write your files. Use permissions like `755` or `750` and `chown` the files and folders to allow the correct user and group to access them.

Comment: This is kind of an XY problem. The question is not about remounted read-only filesystems, but about not being able to change permissions. The underlying problem is a read-only filesystem and not a problem with changing permissions. Given that the asker is using Plesk this is probably not (mis)configured that way, but an artifact of a previous error, like, for example, a corrupted filesystem mounted read-only at boot time.